# <a> tag file download with password

Tags: html, rest, https

I currently have the following functional html which makes a call to my back-end REST API to download a file:

```
<a href="api/downloadFile" download="file.txt">Download File</a>
```

I would like to use a password to protect this kind of request. My website is HTTPS. Will the password be encrypted if I make my back-end api download the file for the following href: "api/downloadFile/{password}"?

The password would be read from the user and dynamically placed in the href like so:

```
<a href="api/downloadFile/passwordFromUser" download="file.txt">Download File</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the password will be encrypted. Only the domain is visible for a man in the middle.

BUT the link will appear in your access log of your server. So you will log the users password.